# How can i make simply countdown in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, countdown

I want to make simply countdown in actionscript 3. Please help me how can I make it simple. 
Note Please show me it with example.

Comment: Could you show us your current code? Or some research you've done?

Comment: Thank you i got answer its great.

Answer (score 1):

You can make countdown this this direction.

Firstly you must creating new textbox in actionscript its instance name must be "Timer"

And we are creating this actionscript codes

```
    // Create the two variables.
var minute = 0;
var second = 0;

// Create the timer
// Checks the clock function every 1000 milisecond (1 second)
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, clock);
timer.start();

// Function that increments the timer
function clock(evt:TimerEvent):void {
// every time this function is checked increment second by one
second += 1;
// If the second is 59
if(second > 59){
// The minute will be plussed with 1
minute += 1;
//and the zero will be set to 00
second = 00;
}
// Displays the time in the textbox
Timer.text = String("Time is: ["+minute+":"+second+"]");
}
```

if you want to see this game example [click here](http://www.truckgamesxl.com) and see! The countdown usually using in game programing. you can see much more truck game example in this site. example you must park truck in 2 min.